# proper youtube url regex to validate url inputs

Tags: regex, video, youtube

I have tried and tested many youtube url regexes and many of them work fine...but I have a problem with these:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdyo-up3Cp0
```

and

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdyo-up3Cp0asdffg
```

All the regexes work properly for both of them , they give the same video...

The problem is that only the 11 characters after `v=` are used and any more to the right will yield the same video....

Can anyone please make a turnaround regex for that? and include it in this regex if possible?

Any more than 11 characters after `v=` should be an invalid one for me.

```
(?:http|https|)(?::\/\/|)(?:www.|)(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=|\/ytscreeningroom\?v=|\/feeds\/api\/videos\/|\/user\S*[^\w\-\s]|\S*[^\w\-\s]))([\w\-]{11})[a-z0-9;:@?&%=+\/\$_.-]*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:http|https|)(?::\/\/|)(?:www.|)(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=|\/ytscreeningroom\?v=|\/feeds\/api\/videos\/|\/user\S*[^\w\-\s]|\S*[^\w\-\s]))([\w\-]{11})
```

Try this if you only want to validate the presence of the last 11 characters.